# Why is it recommended to use TestNGCitrusTestRunner instead of TestNGCitrusTestDesigner?

Tags: testng, citrus-framework

Due to the way I set up my Maven projects the default sample Test class suggests extending Test classes with TestNGCitrusTestDesigner while using Citrus version 2.7.6. Hence I worked with the Designer since to do integration tests.

While troubleshooting my projects set up with the Designer I've run into this statement several times:

"It is recommended that you use TestNGCitrusTestRunner."

This statement was not backed up with further statements such as that the Designer might be outdated or faulty besides that the Runner is what should be used with Citrus version 2.7.5 or higher.

Why is it recommended? Does the Runner have advantages in it's usage in comparison to the Designer? Is the Designer in fact outdated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The designer implementation will read all test actions first into a complete test case at design time. As soon as the test case is completely built via Java DSL in the design time the whole test case is executed in a runtime step.

The runner implementation is not having a separation between design time and runtime. The test case and its actions are executed immediately when built with Java DSL. This approach feels more natural to developers as you can access the results of test actions immediately and you can debug the runner execution.

The designer is not able to perform a debug session as you would expect. In addition to that the designer is not capable for mixing custom Java code between test actions.

Designer and runner implementations do support the exact amount of actions and Java DSL fluent API. The designer approach is likely to be deprecated in future as developers keep complaining about the design time to runtime separation.

There is still a todo for the Citrus team to strengthen the runner usage in samples and documentation though.

Please see also the Citrus documentation that tries to explain the different designer and runner approaches with a concrete example: https://citrusframework.org/citrus/reference/html/index.html#writing-test-cases-in-java

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying that. I'll make sure to consult the documentation more often.